# When will the project completed?

Tags: sentence-construction, modal-verbs, word-order, questions, interrogatives

I want to ask about the completion of the construction project, so which of the following questions is correct grammatically?

> When will be the project completed?

or

> When will the project be completed?

or

> When's the project getting completed?

What's the best way to ask this question?

Answer (score 4):

The 'inversion' involved in questions involves the subject changing places with the **first** auxiliary in a verbchain, and **only** the first; all other verbs in the chain come after the subject, in their normal order.

So if this is your declarative sentence:

> The project will be completed [then]

it is only *the project* and *will* which change places:

```
      The project will be completed [then].
            V__     |
         ______|____v
        |      |
        v      V
 When will the project be completed?
```

Comment: We now add ASCII art to the list of arcana mastered by @StoneyB. We're not worthy!

Comment: As long as nobody mistakes it for a swastika.

Comment: I recall a meta Q in which the quærent insisted that the ELL logo evokes the Marlboro cigarettes logo.